# .appxbundle gives a file system error when i try to install

Tags: windows, powershell, appx

I was trying to install the new win-get installer and I got this error when trying to open the .appxbundle file. What am I doing wrong.

[image: Dosent Work]

Comment: What does this have to do with powershell?

Comment: you can install them with powershell

Comment: and I when I was looking for how to fix this I saw a similar post that also had powershell